# How to avoid mutual left-recursion in ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr4, left-recursion

I am writing a grammar to handle scalar and vector expressions. The grammar below is simplified to show the problem I have where a scalar expression can be derived from a vector and a vector can be derived from a scalar. For example, a vector could be a literal `[1, 2, 3]` or the product of a scalar and a vector `2 * [1, 2, 3]` (equivalent to `[2, 4, 6]`). A scalar could be a literal `2` or an index into a vector `[1, 2, 3][1]` (equivalent to `2`).

```
grammar LeftRecursion;

Integer
    : [0-9]+
    ;

WhiteSpace
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;

input
    : expression EOF;

expression
    : scalar
    | vector
    ;

scalar
    : Integer
    | vector '[' Integer ']'
    ;

vector
    : '[' Integer ',' Integer ',' Integer ']'
    | scalar '*' vector
    ;
```

ANTLR4 gives me the error: `The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [scalar, vector]`. This makes sense because `scalar` references `vector` and vice-versa, but at the same time it should be deterministic.

How would I refactor this grammar to avoid the mutual (indirect) left-recursion? I could [expand one of the terms inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122324/2506021), but that would introduce a lot of duplication in the full grammar where there are more alternatives for vector and scalar. I could also [refactor the grammar to have a primary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523441/2506021), but I don't want to allow `scalar '*' scalar` as a valid `vector` alternative. Are there other options?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is no way around it but to expand to eliminate the indirect recursive rule:

```
expression
    : scalar
    | vector
    ;

scalar
    : '[' Integer ',' Integer ',' Integer ']' '[' Integer ']'
    | scalar '*' vector '[' Integer ']'
    | Integer
    ;

vector
    : '[' Integer ',' Integer ',' Integer ']'
    | scalar '*' vector
    ;
```

Comment: Couldn't you avoid the duplication by adding an extra rule? I.e. `vector_literal: '['Integer, Integer, Integer ']'` and use it in `scalar` and `vector`? `scalar: vector_literal '[' Integer ']'`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
scalar
    : Integer
    | vector '[' Integer ']'
    ;

vector
    : '[' Integer ',' Integer ',' Integer ']'
    | scalar '*' vector
    ;
```

gives that you could write an expressions

```
[i,i,i][i] * [i,i,i][i] * ... * [i,i,i]
```

which would render a stack overflow of the parser for java and other languages with limited stack-depth.

I think you should create a different grammatical rule for vector-lookups, it's not a scalar, it just *results* in a scalar, but this should be handled in the parser tree handling, not in ANTLR.

Comment: Almost any grammar could result in unlimited expression depth. Take, for example, a self-referential rule `scalar : Integer | scalar '*' scalar;`. That could be expanded to any length as well `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ... * n`.